# Overlapping <div>'s with floats

Tags: layout, html, css-float

I'm trying to make a page with two overlapping div's, one aligned to the left with the float:left attribute, and the other next to it, but overlapping by means of a negative margin.

Despite all this, I just get text as my output when I preview in browser from Dreamweaver. Problem is, it looks exactly how I want it in DW's preview pane.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAN3X/3/), and [how it looks](http://i1080.photobucket.com/albums/j327/gregorynash/Screenshot2011-05-13at185148.png) in Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping positions of the #img div, and the #titlebar div; AND make sure both are set to 'float:left'.

(#img div first, then #titlebar div in the HTML)

Comment: Same problem, apart from now the text is spaced 160px more to the right (because of the img div being 160px in width, but despite negative margin [-10px]). If an image is put inside the img div, it overlaps the titlebar div, regardless of the z-index. When both are set to float:left however, the text appears under the img div, for some unbeknown reason. Thanks anyway for the fast response.

Comment: The intended behavior looks right to me when both elements are set to float left, and you switch positions of #img and #titlebar...
If you can clarify what exactly the problem is at this point, I'd be happy to help